# Preflight authorization header during CORS on Slim framework

Tags: php, jquery, cors, authorization, slim

Right now i'm having an issue with CORS (cross-origin resource sharing) especially when trying to send authorization to slim api. I've tried to remove the authorization header on jquery, it works like a charm! But i need authorization to pass api key which i have no clue how to bypass the preflight mode (OPTIONS). Here is the javascript code.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:baseApi+'/code/account',
    crossDomain:true,
    xhrFields:{
        withCredentials:true
    },
    beforeSend:function(xhr){
        $overlay.css('display','block');
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization",boot._header);
    },
    complete:function(xhr){
        // complete scope        
    }
});
```

On slim framework, i have set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with the whitelist origin domain (www.example.com). Here is the complete configuration

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] == "http://www.example.com"){
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    }
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, authorization, Content-Type");
}
```

And here are the complete request and response headers

**Response Headers**

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Tue, 14 Feb 2017 14:44:34 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.24 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.24
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, authorization
Content-Length: 514
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

**Request Headers**

```
OPTIONS /code/account HTTP/1.1
Host: api.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Referer: http://www.example.com/account/payout
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,id;q=0.6,ms;q=0.4
Accept: */*
```

I have tried possible solution from others, but no chance to fix this. Always shown 404 with OPTIONS method called, not GET method like it supposed to.

Comment: The code you've shared works. The `Allow-methods` and `Allow-headers` are both in the response headers. The 404 is not generated because of the shared code.

Comment: Slim framework still see it as `OPTIONS` method. And the requested end-point is registered with `GET` method. check this response on browser console `OPTIONS http://api.example.com/code/account 404 (Not Found)`. And it keep going shows `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.example.com/code/account. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404`

Comment: The way I understand it, it's not a `GET` request, it's an `OPTIONS` request which will be followed by a `GET` request afterwards so you may need to register both.

Comment: You are probably better off using a middleware instead of trying to handle the headers manually: https://github.com/tuupola/cors-middleware

Comment: I edited your initial question by adding  the Content-Type keyword to the  Access-Control-Allow-Headers to make your answer correct. It should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researching and investigating, i ended up using CORS middleware for Slim as suggested by @Mika Tuupola. But since i'm using Slim v2, this repo https://github.com/palanik/CorsSlim suitable for me. And if you are using Slim v3, use this repo https://github.com/tuupola/cors-middleware as created by our saviour. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

For Slim Framework 2.4 Version I did a small hack to tackle the Preflight OPTIONS request

```
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
    if($app->request->isOptions()) {
        return true;
        break;
    }
    $app->post('/authenticate', 'authenticateUser');

$app->run();
```

So this will track all OPTIONS requests and return true and it worked for me.

My .htaccess file was like as follows

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
```

Hope this helps.